# What is the diference between a quinoa burger, a quorn burger, and a soya burger?

Tags: vegetarian, vegan, hamburgers, quinoa, seitan

I would like to know, what is the difference between a quinoa burger, a quorn burger, and a soya burger? Are their ingredients all different, or are some of these in common to the above? What about the industrial preparation process? And are quinoa and quorn just brand names of soya?

Comment: The word is burger. I'm not sure what this question is asking - the materials which go into the burger are different in each case.

Comment: True. Apparently the word bergher is used to describe people of half-Sri Lankan half-European ethnicity. My mistake.

Comment: Well, first and foremost, I wanted to know, are their ingredients all different, or are some of these in common to the above? What about the industrial preparation process? And are quinoa and quorn just brand names of soia? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The differences are as follows:

Quinoa is a pseudocerial coming from goosefoot [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinoa). It is one of the trendy "superfoods" because it has a very high nutritional value ánd is gluten free. I have always used it as a grain substitute and do not know if it's any good as the main ingredient for a burger.

Quorn is a meat substitute made of mycoprotein from fungus. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorn). In my personal experience quorn is a very acceptable substitute for ground beef, so a burger made of this material is likely to taste pretty decent.

Soy is a plant material traditionally used for instance in tofu. It has long been used as a meat substitute due to the high protein content. In my humble opinion it has been surpassed by other meat alternatives, mainly because soy based meat alternatives lack in texture.

All very different products then, where most likely the only common factor is the spicing.